# Combining LEFT, SEARCH and REGEXREPLACE

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match

So, I'm helping out someone, and I'm trying to extract only the name of the cancer in the column, without including "Deaths -".

In Column A, the entries all have this pattern, each string below being in it's own separate row...

```
Deaths - Prostate cancer - Sex: Both - Age: Age-standardized (Rate)
Deaths - Breast cancer - Sex: Both - Age: Age-standardized (Rate)
Deaths - Testicular cancer - Sex: Both - Age: Age-standardized (Rate)
Deaths - Non-melanoma cancer - Sex: Both - Age: Age-standardized (Rate)
Deaths - Tracheal, bronchus, and lung cancer - Sex: Both - Age: Age-standardized (Rate)
```

I've been able to extract the name of the cancer, including removing the word "cancer" with this LEFT and SEARCH formula below...

```
=LEFT(A2, SEARCH("cancer", A2)-1)
```

Resulting in the following...

```
Deaths - Breast 
Deaths - Testicular 
Deaths - Non-melanoma 
Deaths - Tracheal, bronchus, and lung
```

But, I can't seem to combine REGEXREPLACE with LEFT and SEARCH in one formula to also take out "Deaths" and the - (dash), leaving only the name of the cancer.

So, the desired result is below...

```
Breast 
Testicular 
Non-melanoma 
Tracheal, bronchus, and lung
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try simple:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A6, "- (.+) cancer")))
```

[image]